# How do I interpret these Memtest86+ results?

Tags: memory, memtest86+, memtest

I recently ran Memtest86+ (5.01) on some Kingston EEC DDR (not 2, 3 or 4) in different configurations in an old A8N-E mainboard. Some of the tests resulted in errors, but now I'm having a hard time interpreting the results.

First I'll list the hardware, then the different configurations tested, and then I'll list other observations about the error. Finally I'll list the conclusions I tried to draw from it.

#### Hardware

- 2x1 GB ECC Kingston KVR
- 1x1 GB non-EEC Kingston KVR
- 2x512 MB EEC Kingston
- Ancient Asus A8N-E mainboard

#### Configs tested that generated the error

- 2x1 GB EEC capable (EEC disabled) — dual channel
- 2x1 GB + 2x512 MB — EEC capable (EEC disabled) — dual channel
- 2x1 GB + 2x512 MB — EEC capable (EEC enabled) — dual channel

#### Configs tested that haven't yet generated an error

- 2x512 MB EEC capable (EEC disabled) — dual channel
- 1x1 GB EEC capable + 1x1 GB nonEEC capable — dual channel
- 1x1 GB EEC capable (EEC disabled)
- 1x512 MB EEC capable (EEC disabled)
- **Update:** 1x1 GB EEC capable + 2x512 MB (EEC enabled)

#### Observations

- The failing address is always the same (39037fdc — 912.4 MB), except once when I guess I switched places of the modules and the address ended up being 79017fdc (1936.4 MB) instead. Subtracting one address from the other gives: 0x79017fdc - 0x39037fdc = 0x3ffe0000 = 1 073 610 752 which is *almost* (?!) exactly one GiB (1 GiB being 1073.74 MB — not 1073.61 MB). It paints the picture that the two modules switched place and that the error followed one of the DIMMs.
- The failing bit is always the same (00020000), no exception. I'm assuming it's the exact same error every time, in the exact same memory cell (terminology?).
- It always fails on "Test 9" called "[Random number sequence]".
- Exclusively running Test 9 seems to shorten the time until failure.
- Only testing the failing address, i.e. only testing megabyte 911-913 does not seem to proportionally speed up the time until failure. For instance, three full passes of Test 9 over the entire 2 GB may result in an error, while 100 passes of Test 9 at the failing megabyte does not.
- Enabling error correction does not prevent the error from occurring.

#### My assumptions

- It's probably not the PSU or mainboard since that would probably result in different addresses / bits
- It's in one of the two 1 GB EEC modules.
- I cannot isolate which one since it doesn't seem to occur when using only one module, nor in dual-channel configuration with a non EEC equivalent

#### My questions

Are my assumptions reasonable? 
Is there something else to be learned from these results?
Are there any particular reasons why some specific non-failing test should be run again?

Comment: Are you having any other issues when using the PC? I may be a false positive

Comment: You have a module with a slow leak in one or more bits at that address. Less time between writing and reading (the smaller test) is not giving enough time for the charge at the gate to leak, and neither apparently is the single stick on it's own.

Comment: I would put in the 2x512 along (good) with one of the 1GB and see if that throws up the error on either of the 1GB sticks. Probably in single channel.

Comment: @Moab Thanks for showing an interest. There's occasional non-responsive USB keyboard at boot (can't enter setup sometimes). Other than that I can't think of anything that cannot be attributed to the memory errors themselves.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you for sharing your insights, that's very interesting. If I understand you correctly, I could even cram in a 1 GB non-EEC for a total of 3 GB, where one channel is 1+1 GB and one is 0.5 + 0.5? Or maybe your point is that that will do nothing but unnecessarily slow down the time to error since it obviously occurs with only 2 GB total... Ok, I think I get it.

Comment: @Mokubai I'm going to try your suggestion, but I have one question: could you elaborate in what way it differs from my test with 1 GB EEC stick + 1 GB non-EEC stick? Asking since the error exclusively popped up in dual channel.

Comment: I wouldn’t mix ECC and non-ECC memory, honestly, doubtful your system would even boot in that configuration

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the suggestion. In all honesty, it does seem to work even better when mixed since that's the only time I could run 2x1 GB without managing to produce the error. But I'll double check to make sure.

Comment: @Mokubai I was unable to reproduce the error with 1x1 GB + 2x512 MB in single channel

Answer (score 0):

Does the RAM work in a different motherboard?

If so, the motherboard or CPU is bad.

> It's probably not the PSU or mainboard since that would probably result in different addresses / bits

There are various layers between RAM and the CPU, one of them is the CPU cache.

Another is the chipset, which is a motherboard component.

Then of course, there's the DIMM socket itself.

A bad trace on the motherboard leading to the chipset or CPU could cause a consistent single bit error.  An issue with one of the pins in the  DIMM slot may do the same thing.

Both of these are far less likely than a bad DIMM so try the RAM in a different motherboard first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I haven't yet had the opportunity to test on another motherboard. It's not obvious to me how the factors you mention could result in the same error in the same bit in the same byte in a total of 2 GB of RAM given that none of them have a 1-to-1 mapping to each byte in RAM (there aren't two billion traces on the board, for example)